# mapReduce gives different results in upgraded 2.2.0

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've been using mongodb 2.0.4 in development, and on deploying to production I failed to realize they were running 2.2.0.  The mapReduce function that I was using is no longer behaving as it was under 2.0.4, and I can't figure out why.

mongodb 2.0.4 (note: M,F,T,I,C,H,R,D should total 144, and does in this example):

```
{
"_id" : "",
"value" : {
    "tag" : "",
    "networth" : 43558505,
    "land" : 201837,
    "alive" : 144,
    "M" : 86,
    "F" : 6,
    "T" : 5,
    "I" : 10,
    "C" : 17,
    "H" : 4,
    "R" : 12,
    "D" : 4,
    "gdi" : 15
    }
}
```

mongo 2.2.0(m+f+t+i+c+h+r+d totals up to 108, when it should total 144)

```
{
"_id" : "",
"value" : {
    "tag" : "",
    "networth" : 43558505,
    "land" : 201837,
    "alive" : 144,
    "M" : 67,
    "F" : 5,
    "T" : 3,
    "I" : 6,
    "C" : 13,
    "H" : 3,
    "R" : 9,
    "D" : 2,
    "gdi" : 15
    }
}
```

Here is the map/reduce functions I'm using:

```
// Map function
var map = function() { 
    var key = this.tag;
    var value = 
    {
        tag: this.tag,
        networth: this.networth,
        land: this.land,
        alive: this.alive,
        gdi: this.gdi,
        gov: this.gov
    };
    emit(key, value);
};
```

Reduce function

```
var reduce = function(k,vals) {
    reducedVals = { tag: k, networth: 0, land: 0, alive: 0, M: 0, F: 0, T: 0, I: 0, C: 0, H: 0, R: 0, D: 0, gdi: 0 };

    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){

        reducedVals.networth += vals[i].networth;
        reducedVals.land += vals[i].land;
        reducedVals.alive += vals[i].alive;
        reducedVals.gdi += vals[i].gdi;     
        if (vals[i].gov == "M") reducedVals.M = reducedVals.M + 1;
        if (vals[i].gov == "F") reducedVals.F = reducedVals.F + 1;
        if (vals[i].gov == "T") reducedVals.T = reducedVals.T + 1;
        if (vals[i].gov == "I") reducedVals.I = reducedVals.I + 1;
        if (vals[i].gov == "C") reducedVals.C = reducedVals.C + 1;
        if (vals[i].gov == "H") reducedVals.H = reducedVals.H + 1;
        if (vals[i].gov == "R") reducedVals.R = reducedVals.R + 1;
        if (vals[i].gov == "D") reducedVals.D = reducedVals.D + 1;
    }
    return reducedVals;
};
```

Perform the map reduce

```
collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: {replace : 'alliances'}, query: {"alive":1}}, function(err, collection) {
    // Mapreduce returns the temporary collection with the results
            db.close();
     });
```

So brief rundown.. the collection has a bunch of scores, in this format:

```
    "alive" : 1,
"countryNumber" : 47,
"deleted" : 0,
"gdi" : 0,
"gov" : "C",
"land" : 20111,
"name" : "AtheistCelebratingXmas",
"networth" : 9793082,
"protection" : 0,
"rank" : 1,
"resetid" : 407,
"serverid" : 9,
"tag" : "Evolve",
"vacation" : 0
```

I'm essentially grouping by `tag`, summing up the `networth`, `land` and `alive` columns. Then checking the `gov` column for its value and summing up the totals of D,R,etc. Is there a particular reason I'm missing for why this won't work correctly in 2.2 vs 2.0.4?  Either way, will the new aggregate commands do this more easily?  I gave it a brief look over, and can get the group by `tag`, with sums for `networth` and `alive` columns to work--but wouldn't know where to begin with the gov column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of the object you `emit` from your `map` function must be the same as the object returned from your `reduce` function.  This is because the results of a `reduce` call can get fed back into `reduce` when MongoDB decides to parallelize your map-reduce.

So you need to change your `map` to assemble the values to `emit` like this so they have the same structure as what's returned from `reduce`:

```js
var value = {
    "tag" : this.tag,
    "networth" : this.networth,
    "land" : this.land,
    "alive" : this.alive,
    "gdi" : this.gdi
};
value[this.gov] = 1;
```

and then update your `reduce` function accordingly.

BTW, given enough docs this would have failed in 2.0.4 as well.  It's just that 2.2 uses different thresholds for when to parallelize.

Comment: thanks, and sorry for the delay in responding.  SO if I am understanding correctly.  Everything in the reduced function should already be defined in the map function? The thing with the example you gave is that this.gov will be one of 8 different letters.  and if its a H, I want to create a column H with a value of 1.  As far as I can tell, your example would assign a value of 1 to a value[this.gov]---am I missing something?

Comment: `value[this.gov] = 1` takes the value of `this.gov` and uses it as a key of `value`.  For example, if `this.gov` is `'H'` it would set `value.H = 1` (which seemed to be what you were looking to do).

Comment: Oh, that makes sense :)  I do appreciate your help.  I'm still new to coding in general, and I figure the best way to learn is to actual do it.  So updating my reduce function I'm still struggling--but I'm trying to grasp it.  I changed my if statements to something like: if (vals[i].M == 1) reducedVals.M = reducedVals.M + 1;  but still not quite working right.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Probably best to start a new question for that.

Comment: Alright, well thanks for your help (if i'm not mistaken you helped me before as well :) ) I'll tinker with it some more and see if I can stumble onto the solution.

Comment: with enough tinkering around I *think* I got it :) Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted JohnnyHK answer as he answered why my code was not working from one version to another; however, I felt I should post what I modified in the code to resolve the issue.

Map Function:

```
var map = function() { 
     var key = this.tag;
     var fields = {
        tag: this.tag,
        networth: this.networth,
        land: this.land,
        alive: this.alive,
        gdi: this.gdi,
        M: 0,
        F: 0,
        T: 0,
        I: 0,
        C: 0,
        H: 0,
        R: 0,
        D: 0
      };
    if (this.gov == "M") fields["M"] = 1
    else fields["M"] = 0
    if (this.gov == "F") fields["F"] = 1
    else fields["F"] = 0
    if (this.gov == "T") fields["T"] = 1
    else fields["T"] = 0
    if (this.gov == "I") fields["I"] = 1
    else fields["I"] = 0
    if (this.gov == "C") fields["C"] = 1
    else fields["C"] = 0
    if (this.gov == "H") fields["H"] = 1
    else fields["H"] = 0
    if (this.gov == "R") fields["R"] = 1
    else fields["R"] = 0
    if (this.gov == "D") fields["D"] = 1
    else fields["D"] = 0

emit(key, fields);
};
```

Reduce Function:

```
var reduce = function(k,vals) {
    reducedVals = { tag: k, networth: 0, land: 0,  alive: 0, M: 0, F: 0, T: 0, I: 0, C: 0, H: 0, R: 0, D: 0, gdi: 0}; 

    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
        reducedVals.networth += vals[i].networth;
        reducedVals.land += vals[i].land;
        reducedVals.alive += vals[i].alive;
        reducedVals.gdi += vals[i].gdi;     
        reducedVals.M += vals[i].M;
        reducedVals.F += vals[i].F;
        reducedVals.T += vals[i].T;
        reducedVals.I += vals[i].I;
        reducedVals.C += vals[i].C;
        reducedVals.H += vals[i].H;
        reducedVals.R += vals[i].R;
        reducedVals.D += vals[i].D;

    }
    return reducedVals;

};
```